# What's the meaning of Optional("nil") in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

Here is my code. If defaults did not ever save the lat, lng, then give it a lat lng.

The problem is error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

when using `self.lat` and `self.lng` after the code below. Every time console print out is

> the saved gps is Optional("nil")

What's the meaning for `Optional("nil")` and the difference from `Optional(nil)`?

I am using Xcode 7.1 and Swift 2.

```
var lat : String = ""
var lng : String = ""

let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
if  defaults.stringForKey("lat") != nil  {
    self.lat = defaults.stringForKey("lat")!
    self.lng = defaults.stringForKey("lng")!
    print ("the saved gps is \(defaults.stringForKey("lat"))")
} else {
    self.lat = "34.7009333"
    self.lng = "135.4942047"
    print ("the init gps is  \(self.lat) , \(self.lng)")
}
```

Comment: You asked for a string. So nil is wrapped as "nil".

Comment: It looks like you are trying to supply default defaults. Do you know about `registerDefaults`?

Comment: thanks a lot , I changed the code to if  defaults.stringForKey("lat") != "nil" , then it is working now .

Answer (score 0):

**it show the actual value...**

```
let digit = sender.currentTitle!
```

suppose your sender value is 10 then output is 10.

suppose your sender value is nil then **app carsh.**

**it show the optional value**

```
   let digit = sender.currentTitle
```

suppose your sender value is 10 then output is optional("10").

suppose your sender value is nil then **app is not carsh.**

& display value like this optional("nil")